# Returning struct with unknown generic type

Tags: rust

I'm working on a small project in Rust where I want to have an app factory.

```
pub fn init_routes(cfg: &mut web::ServiceConfig) {
    cfg.service(index);
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let server = HttpServer::new(|| App::new().configure(init_routes));
    server.bind(("127.0.0.1", HTTP_PORT))?.run().await
}
```

In this case, it's only `App::new().configure(init_routes)`. When the application grows, I'd  like to add more routes and  so on. It's also easy for testing.

When I put it in a function, like the following snippet, it appears to be returning `App<actix_web::app_service::AppEntry>` where the  generic type is private (`AppEntry`).

```
fn create_app() {
    App::new().configure(init_routes)
}
```

I tried to just refer to `-> App<_>` with the Inferred type feature from Rust. This did not work. Can I create this app factory with the correct return type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AppEntry` implements `ServiceFactory<ServiceRequest>`, so you should be able to make use of [`impl Trait`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/impl-trait.html) here:

```rust
use actix_web::dev::{ServiceFactory, ServiceRequest};

fn create_app() -> App<impl ServiceFactory<ServiceRequest>> {
    App::new().configure(init_routes)
}
```

This won't help you if you actually need to name the type of the `App` somewhere, though.

Normally I'd be a bit wary of relying on a private type to implement a trait, in case a future version removes the implementation. But given that [all of the other methods on `App` are bounded by that same trait](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/struct.App.html#impl-App%3CT%3E), I don't think they could do this without it being a breaking change.